# React-Native iOS: RevanueCat In-App Purchase Subscription

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, app-store, revenuecat

I am using RevanueCat In-app purchase subscription in my app. I have also created in-app purchase in app store connect and they approved also and app is live now. But when I open the app store and open my app in app store app(iPhone device) there is price instead of GET button. I don't know why they ask me for purchase before install.
Every user can download that app It's free for limited data then after they can take subscription from app only.

My app has some limits to store data after that user have to take subscription. But First time when they install my app it should be free not show any price.

Please help me with this because I am new in In-App purchase.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends on what kind of in app purchases you chose to implement. Did you implement auto-renewable subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, I have created auto-renewable subscription

Comment: You created your app in the app store as paid app instead of free app.

Comment: Yes, thanks it's worked!@Dpedrinha